Compile time typescript function overloading
There is function overloading in typescript which allows to specify multiple signatures for one implementation:
function sayHello(name: string): string;
function sayHello(name: string[]): string[];
function sayHello(name: unknown): unknown {
  if (typeof name === "string") {
    return `Hello there, ${name}!`;
  } else if (Array.isArray(name)) {
    return name.map((name) => `Hello, ${name}!`);
  }
  throw new Error("Something went wrong");
}

This method is ok if I just want to give Typescript interface for users, however it still produces runtime type check. Conceptually it defies the logic of typed languages because in the end we are the ones who make the type checks not the "language" or transpiler in this case. It is technically possible to write something like this because Typescript transpiler knows the types of parameters passed from callee, so it can make a dispatch.
function sayHello(name: string): string {
  return `Hello there, ${name}!`;
}

function sayHello(name: string[]): string[] {
  return name.map((name) => `Hello, ${name}!`);
}

sayHello("Joe")
sayHello(["Joe", "Ann"])

I see that this can cause a transpiled Javascript to be invalid but compiled names doesn't need to be the same. We can add some markers to the end of each function and use them in the places where the function is used. Is it against the philosophy of the Typescript community?
function sayHello_$1(name) {
  return `Hello there, ${name}!`;
}

function sayHello_$2(name) {
  return name.map((name) => `Hello, ${name}!`);
}

sayHello_$1("Joe")
sayHello_$2(["Joe", "Ann"])


typescript isn't not a compiled language, it's a static type checking language? so i guess there's no way to transpile like you want.

@AlexanderNenashev it's not compiled, but we have a transpilation step when we transform ts to js, so technically we can do whatever we want with the output code.

for a probably perfect case TS transpiling should include only type annotation removed and added TS=>JS features like enums. What you are asking is too far from that. Typescript never was strong to look and track types deep, so good luck to ask this feature you need from the typescript team ‍♂️

I'm not sure what the question is, but it just doesn't work that way. What happens when you call it with string | string[]? When you compile this and import it into a JS project, you would have to know to call sayHello_$1 or sayHello_$2, which is pretty non ergonomic. This second point is the bigger deal killer, because at the moment, the JS ecosystem is not purely TS. The TS maintainer try to keep is close "ts -> remove types -> valid js" as is possible, and this doesn't fit that.

@AlexWayne I guess you're right, this probably will only be possible with type system introduced directly into js

It's a non-goal of the language to emit different JS based on the results of the type system. So it's a non-starter to have sayHello_$1 or sayHello_$2. See the linked q/a above for more information.
